# Can't get onClick working for listView - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-studio, onclicklistener

I'm having trouble making my listView clickable. I've followed a few examples and tried suggestions on historic SO pages, but just not getting it.

I have this code so far that fills my listView. It also conatins code I have tried to use to make it clickable.

```
helper = new TaskDBHelper(Overview.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.BAL, TaskContract.Columns.IP, TaskContract.Columns.STATUS, TaskContract.Columns.CNTRY, TaskContract.Columns.VS},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.sum_view,
            cursor,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.BAL, TaskContract.Columns.IP, TaskContract.Columns.STATUS, TaskContract.Columns.CNTRY, TaskContract.Columns.VS},
            new int[]{R.id.taskTextView, R.id.txtData, R.id.txtIP, R.id.txtStatus, R.id.txtCounty, R.id.imgStatus},
            0
    );


    ListView nList = this.getListView();
    nList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int arg2, long arg3) {
            Log.d("***CLICK***","YES");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Log.d("***CLICK***","NOTHING SELECTED");
        }
    });


    this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Thanks for suggestions. I changed to this

```
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(Overview.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.BAL, TaskContract.Columns.IP, TaskContract.Columns.STATUS, TaskContract.Columns.CNTRY, TaskContract.Columns.VS},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.sum_view,
            cursor,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK, TaskContract.Columns.BAL, TaskContract.Columns.IP, TaskContract.Columns.STATUS, TaskContract.Columns.CNTRY, TaskContract.Columns.VS},
            new int[]{R.id.taskTextView, R.id.txtData, R.id.txtIP, R.id.txtStatus, R.id.txtCounty, R.id.imgStatus},
            0
    );


    ListView nList = this.getListView();
    nList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view,int position, long id) {
            Log.d("***CLICK***","YES");
        }
    });


    this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
```

But get no log file at all from pressing a list view item.

Also, my listView is made up from a separate layout file made of one row which repeats.

Comment: is it `ListActivity` or normal `Activity` having a `ListView` in xml?

Comment: Is that the extends part? It is ListActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setOnItemClickListener`. `setOnItemSelectedListener` is for selecting multiple items.

Try this:

```
nList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position1, long id) {
 Log.d("***CLICK***","YES");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListView.OnItemClickListener` instead of `ListView.setOnItemSelectedListener` to get click event on ListView rows:

```
    nList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, 
                                           View view,int position, long id) {
                // called when listview row selected
          }
     });
```